# NP-Complete reduction

Tags: algorithm, graph, np

The problem states that we want to show that Independent Set poly-time reduces to Relative Prime Sets, more formally `Independent Set <p Relative Prime Sets`.

I need to provide a **reduction f** from ind.set to rel. prime sets, where

**- input of f** must be a Graph G and an integer k, where k denotes the size of an independent set.

**- output of f** must be a set S of integers and an integer t, where t denotes the number of pairwise relative prime numbers in the set S.

**Definition of relative prime sets** (decision version):

> it takes a set P of n-integers and an integer t from 1 to n.
>
> returns yes if there's a subset A of P, with t-many pairwise relative
>   primes. That is, for all a, b in A, it must be true that gcd(a, b) =
>   1.
>
> returns no otherwise

So far I have come-up with what I believe is a reduction, but I am not sure if it is valid and I want to double check it with someone who knows how to do this.

Reduction:

> Let G be a graph.Let k indicate the size of an independent set. Then we
>   want to find-out if there exists an independent set of size k in G.
>   Since this problem is NP-Complete, if we can solve another NP-Complete
>   problem in poly-time, we know that we can also solve Independent Set
>   in poly-time. So we chose to reduce independent set to Relative Prime
>   Sets.
>
> We take the graph G and label its vertices from 1 to n as pr the
>   definition of the input for relative prime sets. Then we find the gcd
>   of each node to every other node in G. We draw an edge between the
>   nodes that have gcd(a, b) = 1. When the graph is complete, we look at
>   the nodes and determine which nodes are not connected to each other
>   via an edge. We create sets for those nodes. We return the set
>   containing the most nodes along with an integer t denoting the number
>   of integers in the set. This is the set of the most relative prime
>   numbers in the graph G and also the greatest independent set of G.

Comment: The reasoning seems correct to me.

Comment: Could you add an example showing how the reduction works on a small graph e.g. with 5 nodes. A picture would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose two graphs, each of four nodes. On graph one, the nodes are connected in a line so that the max-independent set is 2. Graph two is a complete graph each node is connected to each other node, so the max-independent set is 1.

It sounds like your reduction would result in the same set for each graph, leading to an incorrect result for independent set.

Answer (score 0):

equation,S=k*lnW discrete logaritm can`t be broken because is corelated with informational entropy